# Object.freeze to freeze a property? Or how to set a property to be immutable/read-only?

Tags: javascript, immutability

The docs for `Object.freeze()` state that it only allows freezing the object if its primitive type is actually "object". I'm working with some JSON data objects and was hoping to use this to set specific properties to be immutable (e.g. uuid, which is immutable in the db). `Object.freeze()` seemed like the perfect solution, until:

> `TypeError: Object.freeze called on non-object`

Darn.

So, assuming I've got an object (parsed from JSON) like this:

```
{
    "uuid": "765926c1-911e-49b2-b597-48cf0df59a17",
    "firstName": "Bob",
    "lastName": "Dole"
}
```

is there any way I can force uuid to be immutable?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Yes, you need to use `Object.defineProperty` and re-define `uuid` property descriptor to be non-writable and non-configurable:

```
Object.defineProperty(obj, "uuid", { configurable: false, writable: false });
```

`configurable: false` means that from now `uuid` property descriptor can't be defined again. That is, no other sentence will be able to let the property be mutable again.

At the end of the day, `Object.freeze` is like a shortcut which iterates all enumerable properties in a given object and turns them into non-configurable+non-writable ones.

Comment: Gotcha - awesome. Is the value inferred as well?

Comment: @remus: Read the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty. The value can be set using `{value: ... }`

Comment: @slebetman yeah, thanks I did read that. And testing confirmed that if not passed, it infers the value from the original property.

Comment: @remus Well, it's not that it's infering the value from the original property. `Object.defineProperty` can both create a property from a descriptor, or re-configure an existing property descriptor. So if you don't provide a `value`, `get` or `set` property to the descriptor, you're just adding meaning to the already created property